# ASP.Net C# Object Persists after Saving to Session Once

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, persistence

I came across something I didn't expect and am a little perplexed. Maybe it's been a long time since I've felt with this and forgot how it all works.

The basic concept is this:

1. Create an object, call it obj1 (version 1) on page1
2. Save object to session
3. Retrieve object from session on page2
4. Change object on page2, now call it obj1 (version 2), but DO NOT save to session
5. Retrieve object from session on page3
6. Show object data

Expected result: I expect to see data from obj1 (version 1).

Exact Results: I actually see data from obj1 (version 2), even though I did not save the changed object to the session.

I have created a [small project on GitHub](https://github.com/RoLYroLLs/SessionTest) so you can see what I mean.

Comment: `Change object on page2` how are you changing the object? what type of object is it?  I feel like you're changing properties on the object, which would produce the results you see.

Comment: @Jonesopolis, You can see what i men in the project I supplied. It's a User object which I then change the value of the property. Based on what you are saying, the object gets saved back to the session automatically? Or when I retrieve the object from session, all I am really doing is getting a pointer to the object?

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse the [source](https://github.com/RoLYroLLs/SessionTest/blob/master/default.aspx) (see added comments):

```
<script runat="server">
    private Model.User _user;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // _user is stored in the session, the *very same* object
        _user = HttpContext.Current.Session[Model.Common.UserSessionNameValue] as Model.User;

        if (_user == null) {
            _user = new Model.User();
        }

        var submit = Request.Form["Submit"] ?? String.Empty;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(submit)) {
            var strUserId = Request.Form["UserId"] ?? String.Empty;
            var userName = Request.Form["UserName"] ?? String.Empty;
            var email = Request.Form["Email"] ?? String.Empty;
            Int32 userId;
            Int32.TryParse(strUserId, out userId);

            // So, if you update _user's fields. What is stored in the session will be changed as well.
            _user.UserId = userId;
            _user.UserName = userName;
            _user.Email = email;

            // Regardless, if you "saved" back or not
            if (submit.Equals("Submit with Save")) {
                // because the left-hand side and the right-hand side are the same object
                HttpContext.Current.Session[Model.Common.UserSessionNameValue] = _user;
            }
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is what you can do in order to avoid updating it unintentionally:

```
<script runat="server">
    private Model.User _user;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["Submit"])) {
            var strUserId = Request.Form["UserId"] ?? string.Empty;
            var userName = Request.Form["UserName"] ?? string.Empty;
            var email = Request.Form["Email"] ?? string.Empty;
            Int32 userId;
            Int32.TryParse(strUserId, out userId);

            _user = new Model.User()
            {
                UserId = userId;
                UserName = userName;
                Email = email;
            }

            if (Request.Form["Submit"] == "Submit with Save") {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[Model.Common.UserSessionNameValue] = _user;
            }

            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I will mark your answer but can you explain why the sessions value gets updated, as stated in your first part. Thanks!